Double integral over an area A
By definition, the area of $R$ is $A = \iint_R\mathrm dA$.
So the integrand is $1$.
I came across this exercise, which made me realise I don't grasp this fully at all:
$A$ is the area in the first quadrant limited by the curves $y=\frac{1}{x}$, $y=x^{2}$ and $y=2x^{2}$. Calculate the integral $\iint_{A}^{} xy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$.
If this integral is the area, why is the integrand $xy$ and not $1$? I feel very stupid asking this, but I can't seem to get what I'm thinking wrong..
I solved this by dividing the area in two, and then using the intersection between the curves as limits. I added these two areas together, and I got the correct answer, but I'm confused why I don't understand the given integral $\iint_{A}^{} xy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$. Why is there $xy$ in the integrand, instead of $1$? What would happen if this integral was just $A = \iint_A\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$.
These are my integrals, with areas $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$:
$$A_{1}=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}2x^{2}-x^{2}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$A_{2} = \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}}^{1} \frac{1}{x}-x^{2}\,\mathrm dx$$

The integral of $\iint_\limits{A} dxdy$ is a measure of a set $A$, while $\iint_\limits{A} f(x,y)dxdy$ is a "weighted" measure - according to one interpretation, it is the mass of a set $A$ with density $f(x,y)$. Also integral $\iint_\limits{A} f(x,y)dxdy = \iint_\limits{A}\int\limits_{0}^{f(x,y)} dxdydz$ can be understand as measure of cylinder with floor $A$ and roof $f(x,y)$.

The integrand $f$ in $\iint_Af(x,y);dx;dy$ can be anything. It's only when it is $1$ that the integral represents the area. Otherwise, it's just an integral.

A single integral $\int_a^b\text dx$ is the measure of the distance from $a$ to $b$, while with a function $\int_a^bf(x)\text dx$ is the area under the curve $f(x)$.  In the same way, a double integral over no function measures the area of the boundaries of the double integral, while with a function it measures the "volume under the surface" given by the function...

Here there are two different uses of the word "area": it can refer to either a region or its size. The use of the word in "A is the area..." is the former.

@MPW But if the integral $\iint_{A}^{} xy dxdy$ does not represent the area, why is the solution to the exercise (according to my book) the area? They solved  $\iint_{A}^{} xy dxdy$ by changing variables. I just found the two areas separately by setting up my own integrals, and then adding them together. I don't understand why my solution is the same as theirs, if the integral is not representing an area.

Can you show specifically what the solution in the text was? It's hard to explain it if we can't see it...
